# Twitter bootstrap table border issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap table right border doesn't wrap the table if number of columns are too many, as shown in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sCAUv/2/
Here in the example, the right border stops at h18. I would like it to wrap the table.
How do I fix this?

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>h1</th>
        <th>h2</th>
        <th>h3</th>
        <th>h4</th>
        <th>h5</th>
        <th>h6</th>
        <th>h7</th>
        <th>h8</th>
        <th>h9</th>
        <th>h10</th>
        <th>h11</th>
        <th>h12</th>
        <th>h13</th>
        <th>h14</th>
        <th>h15</th>
        <th>h16</th>
        <th>h17</th>
        <th>h18</th>
        <th>h19</th>
        <th>h20</th>
        <th>h21</th>
        <th>h22</th>
        <th>h23</th>
        <th>h24</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: clear your cache pls.. Dont find any issue...

Comment: Same as other comments, it works fine for me

Comment: Are you using internet explorer ?

Comment: I am using google chrome. it doesnt work for me. works on firefox. checked.

Comment: Working fine in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I see **exactly** what you mean. The problem is that tables can't be wrapped. If they could, how will you know if it's overflow text or if it's a new row?

It's impossible to avoid this kind of issue, unless you want to split the table into two separate tables.

For the others who are curious about what he's talking about, look at this screenshot:

[image: Verbose description of the original posters' issue.]

*In the screenshot above, there is a horizontal scroll bar, which can be obtrusive to website visitors.*

As of now, there isn't any way to wrap a table down without a *lot* more user confusion being caused (which would be even worse than having the scroll bar.

A lot of this issue can be resolved by modifying the screen resolution, or even font size of the `table` element. Such as:

```
table {
    font-size:90% !important;
}
```

Also keep in mind that you should keep the `!important` modifier, as Twitter-Bootstrap tends to override some custom CSS in *some* cases.

I don't recommend trying to wrap the table down whatsoever. It would become very user unfriendly, and would probably contrast to an engaging website.

Comment: this was not what i meant. i dint mean to wrap the whole table inside the area. i meant to have the border wrap the table, even after the scroll bar which is not happening for me.. even though it seems its working for most people

Comment: @AnirudhaPatro Once again, that's impossible. "It seems it's working for most people", it's not. They didn't understand the question.